# nixos-rebuild value is a function while a set was expected

Tags: nix, nixos

Can no longer rebuild - now to debug this?

```
$ sudo nixos-rebuild build --show-trace
building Nix...
error: while evaluating the attribute 'config' at /nix/var/nix/profiles/per-user/root/channels/nixos/nixos/lib/eval-config.nix:64:5:
while evaluating the attribute 'config' at /nix/var/nix/profiles/per-user/root/channels/nixos/lib/modules.nix:96:25:
...
user/root/channels/nixos/lib/modules.nix:195:9:
while evaluating 'addMeta' at /nix/var/nix/profiles/per-user/root/channels/nixos/lib/modules.nix:173:19, called from /nix/var/nix/profiles/per-user/root/channels/nixos/lib/modules.nix:195:18:
value is a function while a set was expected, at /nix/var/nix/profiles/per-user/root/channels/nixos/lib/modules.nix:195:27
```

here are the channels

```
$ sudo nix-channel --list
nixos https://nixos.org/channels/nixos-20.03
nixos-unstable https://nixos.org/channels/nixos-unstable
nixpkgs https://nixos.org/channels/nixpkgs-unstable
```

and tried clearing `sudo rm -rf  /nix/var/nix/profiles/per-user/root/` to no effect

Comment: Could you post the full stack trace? The current lines don't provide much context. You could also try to comment out some of your recent additions and/or post the relevant parts of your configuration.

Comment: here's the whole trace https://gist.github.com/vii/31d1e2f9d33405132c89a4899fe2eb61 - I'll try and comment out bits of my config; I was confused as that is never mentioned

Comment: @JohnFremlin have you tried updating your channels ? with `sudo nix-channel --update ` .